# Spring Boot POST Request specific payload not being accepted

Tags: java, spring-boot, http, curl, post

I have a post request handler setup in my spring boot app that is acting as a response entity. I have a hash map that contains a string value and string key. I am comparing the RequestBody param with the mapped key which should be the input that user is posting and then it spits out the mapped value.

When I do this curl command:

```
curl -d "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0" -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' http://localhost:9119/prediction
```

It returns with the custom entity response error message that it is the wrong payload even though it matches up with my string input contained in the hash map.

```
return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Inccorect payload");
```

Am I comparing the strings wrong?

Here is controller class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.validation.annotation.Validated;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@Validated
@RestController
public class MockController {

    @Autowired
    MockEndPoint mockendpoint;
    @Autowired
    MockConfig mockconfig;



    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index() {
        return "hello!";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/prediction", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = {"application/json"},consumes= "text/plain")
    public ResponseEntity<String> payloader(@RequestBody String params ) throws IOException{
        HashMap<String,String> x = mockconfig.getHM();
        if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[0])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input1)); 
            }
        else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST).body("Inccorect payload amount(18 parameters required");
        }



    }


}
```

My config class:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class MockConfig {

    String input1 = "ncs|56-2629193|1972-03-28|20190218|77067|6208|3209440|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0";
    String input2 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20181213|73630|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|33.35";
    String input3 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20190103|73630|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|0.0|33.35";
    String input4 = "ncp|56-2629193|1955-11-28|20190213|73700|6404|182232|self|-123|-123|-123|0.0|20.0|325.0|0.0|0.0|269.28|269.28";
    @Autowired
    MockEndPoint mockendpoint;

    private HashMap<String,String> hm = new HashMap<String,String>();


    public HashMap<String,String> getHM() throws IOException {
        hm = new HashMap<String,String>();
        hm.put(input1,mockendpoint.Payload1());
        hm.put(input2,mockendpoint.Payload2());
        hm.put(input3,mockendpoint.Payload3());
        hm.put(input4,mockendpoint.Payload4());
        return hm;
    }

}
```

My endpoint class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.util.ResourceUtils;

@Configuration
public class MockEndPoint {





    @Bean
    public String Payload1() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload1.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }


    @Bean
    public String Payload2() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload2.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }
    @Bean
    public String Payload3() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload3.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }
    @Bean
    public String Payload4() throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("src/test/resources/Payload4.txt");
        String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
        return content;
    }


    }
```

I'm not sure what's really causing this error but I have a feeling its coming from trying to compare the string param with the first key, maybe it doesn't like that I casted it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think issue with following code. you are getting keyset of `HashMap` x and checking with first key in it against your payload. but since you are using `HashMap` it may not give you the order in which you have inserted entries in it. you can replace the `HashMap` with `LinkedHashMap` and your code will work as expected since it maintains the insertion order.

```
if(params.equals((String) x.keySet().toArray()[0])) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok(x.get(mockconfig.input1)); 
            }
```